# Does Breeze require jQuery when used with AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, breeze

I am confused about using Breeze. I have looked through the documentation but did not see an answer for this.

When I use Breeze with ASP MVC4 and AngularJS, is it necessary for me to have the jQuery script loaded also?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Updated Answer 10/15/2013]**

(Fixed the date)

As of Breeze 1.4.4, we now support an angular ajax adapter that uses $http.  See the 1.4.4 release notes for more details. *So JQuery is no longer a requirement.*

---

Breeze uses JQuery to provide its default ajax support, independent of Angular. This is provided by the breeze.jquery.ajax adapter and is pluggable. This means that you can either use JQuery or provide an alternative ajax adapter.  Breeze's Angular support will work with either.

Out of the box, though, JQuery is necessary.

We will very likely provide an alternative ajax adapter that uses Angular's ajax implementation at some point in the next few months. Note that no code will need to change when this occurs, other than configuring breeze to use an alternate adapter.

Comment: thanks. Good to hear that you might provide an ajax adapter. We're trying to move the code for our application to Angular (without jQuery). It would be a shame to have to include the jQuery just to meet the Breeze requirement.

Answer (score 0):

As described in [Customizing AJAX](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/customizing-ajax), you can configure Breeze to use Angular's `$http` service instead of jQuery like this:

```js
breeze.config.initializeAdapterInstance('ajax', 'angular').setHttp($http);
```

Answer (score 0):

No. Just do this:

```
breeze.config.initializeAdapterInstance("ajax", "angular");
```